# Insert Uuid in ltree type column in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a following table,

```
CREATE TABLE ProductCode_Timeline
(
    "Uuid" uuid,
    "Descriptions" text,
    "Hierarchy" ltree,

)
```

In above table's "Hierarchy" column, I want to add `uuid` as path reference.
Something like this e.g.

```
INSERT INTO ProductCode_Timeline (Uuid, Descriptions, Hierarchy) VALUES ( '3a037b24-a7d8-11e6-894d-a4db30217df5', "Test", '');

INSERT INTO ProductCode_Timeline (Uuid, Descriptions, Hierarchy) VALUES ( '4a037b24-a7d8-11e6-894d-a4db30217df5', "Test1", '3a037b24-a7d8-11e6-894d-a4db30217df5');

INSERT INTO ProductCode_Timeline (Uuid, Descriptions, Hierarchy) VALUES ( '5a037b24-a7d8-11e6-894d-a4db30217df5', "Test2", '3a037b24-a7d8-11e6-894d-a4db30217df5.4a037b24-a7d8-11e6-894d-a4db30217df5');
```

I am getting incorrect syntax error when trying to add `uuid` in Hierarchy path (as shown in above example).

How to add the Uuid in Hierarchy path? How to handle such kind of scenarios in Postgres?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *A label is a sequence of alphanumeric characters and underscores (for example, in C locale the characters A-Za-z0-9_ are allowed). Labels must be less than 256 bytes long.* from [`ltree` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html)

Comment: Thanks pozs. I have replace the - with _ in my uuid and it is inserting properly. But now i am trying to fetch it with where clause which is something like this  WHERE Hierarchy <@ '<Uuid with _ instead of - >' . This is giving me error as ERROR:  could not find range type for data type "Research".ltree. However, If I ran the same WHERE clause as WHERE "Hierarchy"::text ~ '<Uuid with _ instead of - >' it runs properly. I have created the indexs GIST and btree on Hierarchy column. What could be the posible solution to this?

Comment: I think you might installed the `ltree` module under the `"Research"` schema, and while you are querying, that schema is not in the `search_path`. Put it in the `search_path` with f.ex. `SET search_path TO "MyOtherSchema", "Research";` or use the explicit schema syntax: `Hierarchy OPERATOR("Research".<@) 'xxxx_xxxx_...'`.

Comment: On a side-note: why don't you just use a `parent_id` for hierarchy? PostgreSQL supports [recursive queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: Thanks pozs for the comments. It really helped me to resolve my issue.